# Scroll event is not firing

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have to display more images as the user scrolls down the browser window.I have
created a directive for that.But scroll event is not getting fired.

```
app.directive('whenScrolled', function() {
  return function(scope, elm, attr) {
    var raw = elm[0];

    elm.bind('scroll', function() {
      if (raw.scrollTop + raw.offsetHeight >= raw.scrollHeight) {
        scope.$apply(attr.whenScrolled);
      }
    });
  };
});
```

In LoadMoreItems, I am pushing two new items into the list:

```
function LoadMoreItems() {
  $scope.temp = $scope.allItems[$scope.lastCount];

  $scope.items.push({
    Name: $scope.temp.Name,
    Price: $scope.temp.Price,
    StockStatus: $scope.temp.StockStatus,
    Picture: $scope.temp.Picture
  });
  $scope.temp = $scope.allItems[$scope.lastCount + 1];
  $scope.items.push({
    Name: $scope.temp.Name,
    Price: $scope.temp.Price,
    StockStatus: $scope.temp.StockStatus,
    Picture: $scope.temp.Picture
  });

  $scope.lastCount += $scope.count;
}
```

The below function brings all the items specific to the category.

```
function getAllItemss(cat) {
  itemsFactory.getSpecificItems(cat)
    .success(function(_items) {
      $scope.allItems = _items;

      //$scope.items = [];
      $scope.lastCount = 0;

      LoadMoreItems();
    })
    .error(function(error) {
      $scope.status = 'Unable to load items : ' + error.message;
    });
}
```

HTML:

```
<div when-Scrolled="LoadMoreItems()"></div>
```

Comment: Indent your code please

Answer (score 4):

From the [scroll](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/) docs:

> The `scroll` event is sent to an element when the user scrolls to a
>   different place in the element. It applies to `window` objects, but also
>   to scrollable frames and elements with the `overflow` CSS property set
>   to `scroll` (or `auto` when the element's explicit height or width is less
>   than the height or width of its contents).

So, try to set `scroll` css property on your `div`, or bind event listener to [$window](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24window) object(e.g. `$($window).bind('scroll',listener)`) and do your calculation according to it.

Comment: By digging more into this, I came to know that if I want to pass a function name as attribute value, then I need to define a isolated scope for it and create a listener for the scroll event.

Comment: But it's also not working.  app.directive('whenScrolled', function       ($document)  {
    return {
        scope: {
            restrict: 'C',
            action: '&ngScroll',
            link: function (scope, elm, attr) {var handler = scope.action();
                $(elm).scroll(function (e) { handler(); });
            }
        }        
    };
});  HTML:-  <div id="page" class="when-scrolled" ng-scroll="LoadMoreItems()" style="overflow:auto;">

Comment: Thanks a lot for this reminder , it was very useful for me

Comment: This solution helped me solve a similar issue. I was using angular material library and the ui-view was wrapped with a md-content which cause scroll not to trigger and as Engineer mentioned the main issue was due to the scroll property. after replacing md-content with a div (Actually the md-content shouldn't have been there in the first place.) my issue was solved.  