# Scroll event not binding inside directive - angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive

I have made one [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/wPxxfHVYMnzDp4Ib77DJ?p=preview) where I want to hide **To The Top** button initially and the show it when the screen is scrolled down. I am not able to capture `scroll` event inside directive. I have followed below Urls:

1. [Scroll event is not fired inside directive - angular.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21989923/scroll-event-is-not-fired-inside-directive-angular-js)
2. [Scroll event is not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22954423/scroll-event-is-not-firing)

I have even added the `overflow: scroll;` class to main div, as per suggested by the second url

What am I missing here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are not scrolling the element itself.
you are scrolling the document, so it should be something like:

```
$document.bind('scroll', ...)
```